# How to validate an XML document against an XSD schema using JDom

Tags: java, validation, jdom

I am working on an application that used JDom for parsing **XML** documents.

Following is the existing code:

```
private Document openDocumentAtPath(File file) {

        // Create a sax builder for building the JDOM document
        SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();

        // JDOM document to be created from XML document
        Document doc = null;

        // Try to build the document
        try {

            // Get the file into a single string
            BufferedReader input =  new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader( file ) );
            String content = "";
            String line = null;
            while( ( line = input.readLine() ) != null ) {
                content += "\n" + line;
            }

            StringReader reader = new StringReader( content );
            doc = builder.build(reader);


        }// Only thrown when a XML document is not well-formed
        catch ( JDOMException e ) {
            System.out.println(this.file + " is not well-formed!");
            System.out.println("Error Message: " + e.getMessage());
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Cannot access: " + this.file.toString());
            System.out.println("Error Message: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return doc;
    }
```

Now I also want to validate the XML against an **XSD**. I read the [API](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs.1.1/index.html?org/jdom/input/package-summary.html) and it tells to use JAXP and stuff and I don't know how.

The application is using **JDom 1.1.1** and the examples I found online used some classes that are not available in this version. Can someone explain how to validate an XML against an XSD, especially for this version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about simply copy-pasting code from the [JDOM FAQ](http://www.jdom.org/docs/faq.html#a0360)?

Answer (score 2):

Or, use JDOM 2.0.1, and change the line:

```
SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
```

to be

```
SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder(XMLReaders.XSDVALIDATING);
```

See the JDOM 2.0.1 javadoc (examples at bottom of page): http://hunterhacker.github.com/jdom/jdom2/apidocs/org/jdom2/input/sax/package-summary.html

Oh, and I should update the FAQs

Comment: does JDOM2 support XSD 1.1? (specifically `xs:assert`) ? I googled but still can't figure out the answer

Comment: @ycomp - JDOM does not do the actual parsing, it uses the underlying parser (typically xerces, or the version of xerces packaged with Java) to do that. JDOM just does the in-memory model. Xerces does support XSD1.1 I believe, see: http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/xml-schema.html#supported-schema-1.1-features